# Installing Steam on Ubuntu 13.10 - Need Execute Permissions

Tags: 13.10, permissions, hard-drive, intel, steam

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 for the first time (new desktop, figured I'd grab a Linux partition).
I had a partition of a second hard drive I wanted to use for Linux file storage. I went to put my Steam library there, but apparently I don't have execute permissions and so couldn't do it.
I tried giving permissions to my group as another forum member suggested in another post (in Files >  Properties), but as soon as I changed the settings they immediately changed back.
How can I get this to work?

Cheers.

Comment: You need to allow Steam to be located where the files can be accessed and executed. This means you should place this into a drive where you will have permissions. Root is the only user that mounts file systems at the partition level and altering the system to allow a user root permissions is really not the right way to do that. Increasing the size of your /home partition might be a better alternative. You can store files in another directory, but don't believe that this will be accessible without a lot of extra work that isn't really advisable from a security standpoint.

Comment: Let me clarify - the primary installation is on a small partition on an SDD, so increasing the size of my home partition is not an alternative.
I'm willing to do a bit of work in the terminal if need be, but I have no idea which commands to use.

Answer (score 0):

If is NTFS you need to edit /etc/fstab and add your partition there with `exec` option to allow execution of binary files.

Comment: It's NTFS; used GParted to partition it and Ubuntu automatically mounted it.

Comment: How exactly would I go about doing that? What would I insert in the text file?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab